# Given is an array numbers with integers. Return true if a zero is next to a zero or a four is next to a four. Return false if both occure

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

It should return true if 0,0 or 4,4 occur, or returns false if both occur.
either404([0,0,3,6,4,4]) should return false, but it returns true

```
function either404(numbers) {
  for (let i =0; i<= numbers.length-1; i++){
    if(numbers[i] === 0 && numbers[i+1] === 0 || numbers[i] === 4 && numbers[i+1] === 4){
      return true
    } else if(numbers[i] === 0 && numbers[i+1]===0 && numbers[i] === 4 && numbers[i+1] === 4){
    }

  }
  return false
}
console.log(either404([0,0,3,6,4,4]))
```

Comment: the moment your condition becomes true the first time you do `return true` so the code won't iterate any further. So it will return `true` since it found `0` next to a `0` and it won't check the rest of the elements

Comment: Could you help me please with correct code?

Comment: You could add two boolean variables. Initialize both with false. If you find two zeros, set one variable to true. If you find two fours, set the other variable to true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for help, i am still learning JS, sometimes it is hard for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a return inside your loop you could use a flag, set it as true if the conditions are true then evaluate if both flags(`nextto0` and `nextto4`) are true then return `false`, else return `true`

```js
function either404(numbers) {
  let nextto0 = false;//flag for the 0 next to each other condition
  let nextto4 = false;//flag for the 4 next to each other condition
  for (let i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] === 0 && numbers[i + 1] === 0) {
      nextto0 = true;//if condition is met, set to true
    } else if (numbers[i] === 4 && numbers[i + 1] === 4) {
      nextto4 = true;//if condition is met, set to true
    }
  }
  if(nextto0 && nextto4 || !nextto0 && !nextto4){
    //if both conditions were true(or neither of them), return false
    return false;
  } else {
    //else just return true
    return true;
  }

}
console.log(either404([0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 4]))//both occur
console.log(either404([0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 3]))//only one occur
console.log(either404([0, 1, 3, 6, 4, 3]))//neither
```